# Clustering with K-means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm trying to cluster the following "Network" dataset using k-means:

```
       LONGITUDE LATITUDE ALTITUDE
    10  12.35273 60.74066 24.49067
    11  12.35308 60.74080 24.23027
    12  12.35340 60.74090 23.23328
    13  12.35373 60.74100 22.60084
    14  12.35418 60.74106 22.64438
    15  12.35458 60.74115 23.39748
```

I tried this code:

```
NetClu <- kmeans(Network,3)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Any idea what this means or how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have `NA`s in your data?

Comment: Yes, there one that I haven't noticed at the bottom of the data set. I deleted and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe probably has some rows which contain NA values. They are usually causing this type of Error.
Remove the rows that have NA values and then run the kmeans function one more time:

```
Network <- na.omit(Network)
NetClu  <- kmeans(Network,3)
```